# remove quotes from variety's wallpaper

Tags: customization

I am using [Variety](http://peterlevi.com/variety/how-to-install/) to change custom wallpaper on my Linux machine. But, after the recent variety update all wallpapers have random quotes on them and the name of author of the quote.

How do I remove them and have just the wallpaper

Answer (score 1):

Go to Variety's Preferences -> Effects and turn off the option for quotes (or from Variety's menu choose Quote -> Turn off).